# Windows XP: Hard drive is called letter "H:" instead of "C:"

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, drive-letter

I recently installed Windows XP Pro SP3 on an old PC. Everything seemed fine except for the fact that the 1 TB hard drive that I installed it to is called "H:" instead of "C:," like it usually is on Windows systems. The letter "C:" is instead assigned to a "Removable Disk Drive" (I believe one of the card readers that came with the desktop). Will re-installing XP with the card readers disconnected end up naming the HDD to "C:"? Also, will keeping "H:" as the main hard drive name present any possible problems with installing software (in other words, if I can fix it, is it really worth doing so)? Thanks.

Comment: Change the drive letter of the removable drive, then change the drive letter of the system drive, both can be done by drive management

Comment: "if I can fix it, is it really worth it?" - No; Your system works, the drive letter assigned to the system drive, doesn't change the functionality of anything

Comment: You won't be having any specific problems generally speaking when installing software. Drive letter H isn't a problem by itself. You can go ahead and use your current windows installation without any problems. So, it does not worth the effort to change that drive letter to "C:".

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling may not fix the issue.

If the programs you use are written by competent programmers (which is mostly the case) drive letter of OS drive should not be a problem.

Here's a link that might you in renaming drive letter- https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000038.htm

Comment: I thought XP wouldn't let you change the name of the drive that Windows is installed to otherwise it will fail to boot. At least that's what I read when I initially looked this problem up.

Comment: I'd suggest you to move on with your current installation, given that xp ain't no longer secure/supported and that most programs that run on xp are mature. You shouldn't run into any applications related issue anytime soon.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just gonna leave it as drive H:. It won't let me change the boot/system volume. Thanks, though!

Comment: I just reinstalled XP with the card readers unplugged. My drive is now recognized as C:!